# How to create a conditional from a command output, that may throw an exception?

Tags: bash, aws

I've got a command from `aws cloudformation` that returns a stack status in a text format 'DELETE_IN_PROGRESS', or 'ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' and so on:

```
aws cloudformation --region "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" describe-stacks --stack-name "$STACK_NAME" --query 'Stacks[*].StackStatus' --output text
```

It only returns a stack status if the process is ongoing, and if not it throws the following:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeStacks operation: Stack with id `foobar` does not exist
```

So, what I thought is to hide the error message for those exceptions and compute the text output otherwise, so I did:

```
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='us-east-1'
STACK_NAME='blog-review-ci'

until test "$(aws cloudformation --region "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" describe-stacks --stack-name "$STACK_NAME" --query 'Stacks[*].StackStatus' --output text 2>/dev/null)" = 'DELETE_IN_PROGRESS'; do
  echo "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS for $STACK_NAME, wait...";
  sleep 3s;
done
```

Unfortunately, this keeps returning:

```
DELETE_IN_PROGRESS for foobar, wait...
```

Which is not correct, because there's no DELETE_IN_PROGRESS happening at the moment, so not sure why it's passing.

I tried to find more information about the AWS command to understand if the output in the error case is stderr/stdout but I don't know how to find that information.

I also tried to run the command then | grep 'DELETE_IN_PROGRESS' but that hasn't worked:

```
until aws cloudformation --region "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" describe-stacks --stack-name "$STACK_NAME" --query 'Stacks[*].StackStatus' --output text | grep 'DELETE_IN_PROGRESS'; do
  echo "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS for $STACK_NAME, wait...";
  sleep 3s;
done
```

This resulted in:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeStacks operation: Stack with id blog-review-ci does not exist
DELETE_IN_PROGRESS for foobar, wait...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you used `until` where you apparently need `while`.

[Difference between `while` and `until` in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19218287/10765659).